# Linking two Form in Access using VBA

Tags: vba

I have a class form and a student form. I am trying to use VBA to link between the classes and the students. When I double click on the class textbox in the form, I want the student form to display only the students that are enrolled in that class. when I double click on the class form now, it shows all the students regardless of their class. I would appreciate your help very much. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you set up a subform (Students) within a main form (Class)? Then, whenever you navigate Class by Class on main form the corresponding Students will display. No need for VBA.

Just be sure to link the index fields (parent to child) in their underlying recordsources or tables such as ClassID of Class table as parent and ClassID of Students table as child. The Access wizard helps here.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest having the class form displayed in layout view. Then you can set up on click property for the form (as shown below). When you click on a row containing your class it will filter the "students" form accordingly.

If you want to do it using a text box in normal view just set the on click property for the text box.

```
 Private Sub Form_Click()
 'If yours comes from text box you need to set it up in the "on click" property on the text box
 DoCmd.OpenForm "students", acNormal, , "[class] = [Forms]![class]![class]"
 'assmptions: Your students form is called "stuednts" ; Your class form is called "class" ; Your class field is called "class" on both forms
 End Sub
```

(in the layout view) For this to work you need to click left of the row, as if selecting a row in excel.